# I have nested functions in a submenu that are not working as I want it to

Tags: python, function, nested

I have a menu for booking reservations and it writes a reservation list and seating chart to text files every time someone enters a new reservation.

I have a menu that has the option to display the seating chart, purchase a seat, a nested admin menu, or quit. the admin command opens a new menu that lets you clear the contents of the reservation list, return to the main menu, or quit; or at least it is supposed to. I must have something wrong with the error checking, or maybe I cannot build it this way. Can someone see where i am going wrong? I have a large program and can post more, but would rather just post the portions i am having trouble with. the other functions are defined at the main program level(same level as the menu function), should the nested functions also be defined at that level? thanks.

```
 def menu():
    print(
        'Select chioce from menu:\n\nP to purchase an available bus seat\nD to display current bus seat chart\nEnter password (admin) for admin menu\nQ to quit')

    while True:
        try:
            menu_choice = str(input(' \n')).upper()
            if menu_choice == str('D'):
                display()
                break
            elif menu_choice == str('P'):
                book()
                break
            elif menu_choice == str('ADMIN'):
                    def clear_booking(): # the nested functions are not working-
                        print('Clearing bookings')
                        with open("bookings.txt") as f: 
                            f.write("")
                    def previous():
                        menu()            
                    print('CB to clear bookings\nR to return to main menu\nQ to quit')
                    admin_choice = str(input(' \n')).upper
                    if admin_choice == str('CB'):
                        clear_booking()
                    elif admin_choice == str('R'):
                        previous()
                    elif admin_choice == str('Q'):
                        exit()
                    else:
                     print('Invalid choice')
                     exit()  
            elif menu_choice == str('Q'):
                print('exiting program')
                exit()
            else:
                print('Value not recognized.')
                exit()
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid entry')
    return # how do i get rid of the none from this returning correctly?
print(menu())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the () at the `admin_choice = str(input(' \n')).upper` at the upper()  function call.

Also maybe you can return a string with text instead of just `return` at the last line of your menu() function body

Also try to include your problem statement in the introductory text of your question to make it clear what the problem is with your code, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. forgot the (). also, thanks for the tip about adding a string. i was still working on that myself so didn't ask. I added  a ' ' and it worked great. I will remember to put the question up front in the future, i just thought some info would be helpful first. after getting this working i see the clear_bookings function is not clearing my text file, but the other functions work correctly.